# How to call SVN's fs.change_rev_prop2 from Python / SWIG - passing old_value_p as a double pointer?

Tags: python, pointers, svn, swig

I'm trying to call [`fs.change_rev_prop2`](https://subversion.apache.org/docs/api/1.8/group__fs__handling.html#ga42e1c39fc4980da8c2f2f575fa7515ac) from Python / SWIG - and apparently can't figure out how to pass `old_value_p` as what I'm assuming needs to be a double pointer from Python.

Minimized code sample:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from svn import repos, fs, core

fs_ptr = repos.fs(repos.open("/opt/app/svn/repos/test"))
rev_num = 1

user = fs.revision_prop(fs_ptr, rev_num, "svn:author")

# Works, but is is deprecated in favor of fs.change_rev_prop2 .
fs.change_rev_prop(fs_ptr, rev_num, "svn:author", user.lower())

# fs.change_rev_prop2(fs_ptr, rev_num, "svn:author", user, user.lower())
# > svn.core.SubversionException: 160049 - revprop 'svn:author' has unexpected value in filesystem

# fs.change_rev_prop2(fs_ptr, rev_num, "svn:author", None, user.lower())
# Per svn_ra.h: If the capability is not advertised, then @a old_value_p MUST be @c NULL.
# This results in a successful change of the revision property, but then this program ends with a segmentation fault.
```

Details of the # 160049 error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "./normalize-usernames.py", line 10, in <module>
        fs.change_rev_prop2(fs_ptr, rev_num, "svn:author", user, user.lower())
    File "/opt/app/subversion/lib/svn-python/libsvn/fs.py", line 711, in svn_fs_change_rev_prop2
        return _fs.svn_fs_change_rev_prop2(*args)
svn.core.SubversionException: 160049 - revprop 'svn:author' has unexpected value in filesystem
```

I believe the value I'm attempting to pass is "correct".  After all, I'm obtaining it from the API immediately before attempting to set it back.  I'm assuming I'm just not passing the value correctly in a way that the native API can accept it.

So I *could* just continue using `change_rev_prop` - but it is clearly marked as deprecated in the API ("Provided for backward compatibility with the 1.6 API").  Should be able to do better, though...

Interestingly, calling `change_rev_prop2` with `None` for `old_value_p` results in the desired change taking effect in the repository - but not without causing the Python program to then immediately terminate with a Segmentation Fault.

It would seem that I need to pass the old / current value as a pointer - possibly to be able to differentiate to the API the difference between a null pointer (value not provided) and a pointer to a null value (value is provided, but value is null)?  However, I've tried all the combinations I can think of here without success - including using various wrappers from [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html).

SO is appropriately suggesting a good number of questions that may already have the answer here - but it appears that most of them cover cases where the author has control over the C sources and with recommendations to alter the C API to avoid the complexity entirely - which I don't see to be an option here.  This is my only experience with Python and SWIG so far, and any tips would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Not sure, but I doubt that this is a problem with SWIG / passing NULL pointer. My guess is that you are not using the function `change_rev_prop2` correctly. I'll have a quick look at the documentation (hadn't seen you linked it)

Comment: @m7thon - thanks, I hope that's all it is.  Would certainly make things easier.  :-)

Comment: Reading through the source code that gets generated I can't see anyway this isn't a bug. The docs clearly say that you can pass NULL in to the underlying C function, but the wrapper code includes an inescapable `if (*arg4 == NULL)`.